# Fast way to split a string into fixed-length parts in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006

I need to split a string to a TStringList with fixed-length sub-strings.

Currently I use:

```
procedure StrToStringList(ASource: string; AList: TStrings; AFixedLen: Integer);
begin
    Assert(Assigned(AList));
    while Length(ASource) > AFixedLen do
    begin
        AList.Add(LeftStr(ASource, AFixedLen));
        Delete(ASource, 1, AFixedLen);
    end;
    AList.Add(ASource);
end;
```

This works, but seems to be slow. Any better / faster idea?

**Edited: Profiling of the results**:

The speed gain is quite impressive.
Here are the results of my (subjective) profiling.

Data size: 290KB, FixedLen: 100:

- Original code: 58 ms
- Heffernan: 1 ms
- Deltics: 1 ms

Data size: 2805KB, FixedLen: 100:

- Original code: 5803 ms
- Heffernan: 5 ms
- Deltics: 4 ms

Comment: Obviously, `Delete` call is unnecessary.

Comment: It's Rud-y, not Rud-i. I bet you could see that difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some immediately obvious optimisations possible in your code:

1. Do not modify the source string, simply extract the required
   substrings.  You can then make the input string parameter const,
   allowing the compiler to further optimise calls made to the procedure
2. Since you are dealing with fixed lengths and an input string of
   known length, then you can pre-calculate the required capacity of
   the string list and avoid memory re-allocations as the list is added
   to.

Here is how I would go about this:

```
procedure StrToStringList(const aSource: String;
                          const aList: TStrings;
                          const aFixedLen: Integer);
var
  idx: Integer;
  srcLen: Integer;
begin
  aList.Capacity := (Length(aSource) div aFixedLen) + 1;

  idx    := 1;
  srcLen := Length(aSource);

  while idx <= srcLen do
  begin
    aList.Add(Copy(aSource, idx, aFixedLen));
    Inc(idx, aFixedLen);
  end;
end;
```

The capacity calculation here may result in an excess capacity of 1 where the input string divides exactly by the fixed length, but this is a negligible overhead imho and acceptable where the goal is optimal performance (the alternative is a conditional branch to modify or calculate the capacity differently to cater for what is likely to be the minority of cases).

Comment: Accepted, this code seems to be slightly faster than the other one.

Answer (score 7):

I think it is wasteful to modify the input string. Avoid this like this:

```
var
  Remaining: Integer;
  StartIndex: Integer;
begin
  Remaining := Length(ASource);
  StartIndex := 1;
  while Remaining > 0 do
  begin
    AList.Add(Copy(ASource, StartIndex, AFixedLen));
    inc(StartIndex, AFixedLen);
    dec(Remaining, AFixedLen);
  end;
end;
```

This will reduce the amount of heap allocation, and the copying.

However, I would not be surprised if you observed little gain in performance. In order to perform any serious optimisation we'd likely need to see some example input data.

Comment: Yes, your solution is faster. Thanks. This is about preprocessing different chunks of COBOL data that must be read in. Serious optimization would certainly avoid splitting the data into StringLists but at the moment I am looking for ways to optimize without rewriting the underlying structure.

Comment: If the items are fixed length, then string lists may not be the best approach. Character arrays would likely be faster. I'm sure you can do a lot better than the code here, but I don't think we've got enough detail to be more specific.

Comment: After some profiling I am impressed how fast that TStringList-based approach actually is. The COBOL data is splitted into datasets by the function here. Afterwards dataset by dataset is parsed from the stringlist. No need for further optimization on this front at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `delete` inside the loop. It causes the whole string to move. Use an `integer` based index variable starting at 1 and increase it each time by `AFixedLen` after you have used `copy` to extract the substring until you reached the end.