# How do I split a string into an array of fixed-length substrings?

Tags: delphi, pascal, lazarus, freepascal

i try to make a string which has many character,

```
var
a: String;
b: array [0 .. (section)] of String;
c: Integer;
begin
a:= ('some many ... text of strings');
c:= Length(a);
(some of code)
```

and make it into array per 10 character. at the last is the remnant of string.

```
b[1]:= has 10 characters
b[2]:= has 10 characters
....
b[..]:= has (remnant) characters   // remnant < 10
```

regards,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fast way to split a string into fixed-length parts in Delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31943087/fast-way-to-split-a-string-into-fixed-length-parts-in-delphi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dynamic array, and calculate the number of elements you need at runtime based on the length of the string. Here's a quick example of doing it:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

var
  Str: String;
  Arr: array of String;
  NumElem, i: Integer;
  Len: Integer;
begin
  Str := 'This is a long string we will put into an array.';
  Len := Length(Str);

  // Calculate how many full elements we need
  NumElem := Len div 10;
  // Handle the leftover content at the end
  if Len mod 10 <> 0 then
    Inc(NumElem);
  SetLength(Arr, NumElem);

  // Extract the characters from the string, 10 at a time, and
  // put into the array. We have to calculate the starting point
  // for the copy in the loop (the i * 10 + 1).
  for i := 0 to High(Arr) do
    Arr[i] := Copy(Str, i * 10 + 1, 10);

  // For this demo code, just print the array contents out on the
  // screen to make sure it works.
  for i := 0 to High(Arr) do
    WriteLn(Arr[i]);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Here's the output of the code above:

```
This is a
long strin
g we will
put into a
n array.
```

Comment: FWIW, instead of `NumElem := Len div 10; if Len mod 10 <> 0 then Inc(NumElem);` you can do `NumElem := (Len + 9) div 10;`, which is a little shorter.